Could not set unknown property 'jar' for extension 'launch4j' of type edu.sc.seis.launch4j.Launch4jPluginExtension
Hi I am getting above error in app.gradle while building gradle project. I am using gradle version 8.8. Below is my app.gradle file. Can someone please help with this. I have recently upgraded gradle from 5.2 to 8.8. After upgrading I have got below issue.
 buildscript {
              repositories {
                  maven {
                      url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
                  }
              }
              dependencies {
                classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.1.5"
                classpath "edu.sc.seis.launch4j:launch4j:3.0.6"
                classpath "com.gorylenko.gradle-git-properties:gradle-git-properties:2.4.2"
              }
            }
            
            apply from: "${buildscript.sourceFile.parent}/java.gradle"
            apply plugin: org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin.SpringBootPlugin
            apply plugin: edu.sc.seis.launch4j.Launch4jPlugin
            apply plugin: com.gorylenko.GitPropertiesPlugin
            
            // the spring boot plugin uses the bootJar task instead of jar
            bootJar.manifest.attributes = jar.manifest.attributes
            bootJar {
            //    archiveBaseName = "${project.name}-exec.jar"
                archiveFileName.set("${project.name}-exec.jar")
            }
            
            launch4j {
                mainClassName = "org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher"
                jar = "${buildDir}/libs/${project.name}-exec.jar"
                outputDir = "libs"
                headerType = "console"
               // icon = "${projectDir}/src/main/resources/favicon.ico"
                copyright = "test"
                companyName = "test"
                internalName = "test"
                bundledJrePath = "./jre"
            }
            
            build.finalizedBy createExe


it looks like you updated Launch4J plugin version, not only Gradle version ?  there is no such property jaron launch4j extension anymore, please refer to https://github.com/TheBoegl/gradle-launch4j?tab=readme-ov-file#how-to-configure
